# casting a constant to be used as a pointer

Tags: c++, casting, uint32-t

I've been using some example code that runs in an ARM processor. To read a specific memory location it casts a constant value to an address.

For example:

We want to read a memory value at 0xa0000000

The example code is like this:

```
uint32_t test_data;

const uint32_t test_address = 0xa0000000;

test_data = *(uint32_t*) test_address;
```

I don't quite understand the cast *(uint32_t*). It seems to me that just one * is enough.

I'd appreciate a bit of explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: `(uint32t *)` casts the address to a pointer. But you don't want to read the pointer value itself (because you have already got it, it's the constant) – you want to read the memory that is pointed to by that pointer, which you achieve by **dereferencing** the pointer using the `*` operator.

Comment: `*op` makes no sense (compiler error) if x is an integer type. It makes sense if `op` is a pointer: it is the dereference oeprator and it dereferences the pointer `op`. Since `test_data` is an integer type, a cast to a pointer is needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing a pointer as a uint32_t instead of a pointer to uint32_t.  That's why you have to do the additional cast.

I'd recommend the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    volatile uint32_t* const test_address = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(0xa0000000);
    uint32_t value = *test_address;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it make sense to make `test_address` a pointer to `volatile` as well? Might need that if it's actually a memory-mapped I/O address or something.

Comment: Yeah, probably.  I don't have a CPU to test it on, but I think you're right.  Thanks, Fred.

Answer (score 1):

The cast `(uint32_t*) test_address` reinterprets the value of `test_address` as an address, and yields a pointer pointing to that address. This C-cast has the same effect a `reinterpret_cast` would have - and really, `reinterpret_cast` should be used instead.

To get the value that pointer is pointing too, i.e. its pointee, it is necessary to dereference it via `*`. That gives us `* ((uint32_t*) test_address)`, or equivalently `*(uint32_t*) test_address`.

Answer (score 0):

its clearer if you split

```
test_data = *(uint32_t*) test_address;
```

into two steps

```
uint32_t  *p = (uint32_t*) test_address;
test_data = *p;
```

The first is the cast, the second is the dereference